# Integrating Web Form and MVC projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

I am integrating an MVC project with my current Web Forms Application. I used Nuget to install MVC into the solution (based on some reading I did, which suggested doing this will add the binaries and configuration necessary). I then added a new MVC project into the solution and edited the Global.asax.vb file as following for MVC Routes:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
     MVC.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

But when I run the application I get the following error:

```
System Error

The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched 
locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx 
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx 
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml 
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: do you have the right views folders?

Comment: I created a new MVC project into the solution, which contains all the necessary folders.

Comment: you have to set MVC routing to ignore all .aspx

Comment: Can I get a code snippet of how I would go about doing this?

Comment: I added routes.IgnoreRoute("{*aspx}")  to the RouteConfig and it works but the MVC routes are not working